# Drawing onto a Java2D Path using several Transforms

Tags: java, graphics2d, java-2d

I have a fairly complex list of short line segments that taken together form a line.

I'd like to take this line and draw it 4 times along the 4 edges of a polygon. Obviously, for each side of the polygon I'll need to rotate the line by 90 degrees and translate it to it's final position.

After drawing this polygon with irregular sides I'd like to fill it.

I have the folowing code:

```
  private void drawSide(GeneralPath path, int startX, int endX, int y)
    {
    path.moveTo(startX, y);
    
    // in reality this is very complex, but for now, just draw a line
    path.lineTo(endX, y);
    }
  
  private AffineTransform getTransform(int deltaX, int deltaY, int angle)
    {
    AffineTransform rat = new AffineTransform();
    rat.translate(deltaX, deltaY);
    rat.rotate(Math.toRadians(angle));
    return rat;
    }
  
  private void test(Graphics2D g2d)
    {
    GeneralPath path = new GeneralPath(GeneralPath.WIND_EVEN_ODD);

    drawSide(path, 100, 200, 100);

    path.transform(getTransform(100, 0, 90));  
    drawSide(path, 100, 200, 100);
    
    path.transform(getTransform(100, 100, 180));  
    drawSide(path, 100, 200, 100);
    
    path.transform(getTransform(0, 10, 270));  
    drawSide(path, 100, 200, 100);
    
    path.closePath();
    g2d.fill(path); 
    g2d.draw(path);
    }
```

I don't really understand what's wrong here. Can anyone help?

Comment: I "think", when applying a transform to a shape, you're applying it to WHOLE shape, not just the next operation

Comment: @MadProgrammer  I was thinking that was true, but couldn't find a reference. In any case, I want to draw the same set of operations 4 times, each rotated 90 degrees. How SHOULD I do it??

Comment: Use 4 paths and then join them together ;)

Comment: [`Path2D#transform`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/geom/Path2D.Float.html#transform(java.awt.geom.AffineTransform))- *"Transforms the geometry of this path using the specified AffineTransform. The geometry is transformed in place, which permanently changes the boundary defined by this object."*

Comment: @MadProgrammer  Hmmm, didn't see that. I don't see anything about "joining" paths, but I do see how one can create multiple subpaths each with it's own transform and then append them into a master path. Is this what you're suggesting?

Comment: `GeneralPath#append(Path, boolean)` <- Append paths.  Also, when I tested your code, you'll need to apply the transformation (to the subpath) AFTER you've applied the line

Comment: @MadProgrammer  Yup. It works!! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I want to point out is, I'm an idiot.  So the first thing I try to do is find a workflow which my cognitive facilities can grasp.

What does this mean?  There's probably a better solution, but I can't see it right now.

I did try doing a "local" context workflow, which would simply apply 90 degrees of rotation at each step, but that ended in a mess, so, I stuck with a "world context" workflow

This just means that the rotation/translations are based on the "world context" as apposed to the local context of the last change, yea for me

So, the basic idea is to start with a basic line `Path`, then create a new `Path` for each segment, appending the "base" `Path` to and applying appropriate transformations, for example

```
protected Path2D worldContext() {
    // Our "base line" line
    Path2D baseLine = new Path2D.Double();
    baseLine.moveTo(0, 0);
    baseLine.lineTo(100, 0);

    // Top line
    Path2D line1 = new Path2D.Double();
    line1.append(baseLine, true);

    Path2D line2 = new Path2D.Double();
    line2.append(baseLine, true);
    line2.transform(AffineTransform.getTranslateInstance(100, 0));
    line2.transform(AffineTransform.getRotateInstance(Math.toRadians(90), 100, 0));

    Path2D line3 = new Path2D.Double();
    line3.append(baseLine, true);
    line3.transform(AffineTransform.getTranslateInstance(100, 100));
    line3.transform(AffineTransform.getRotateInstance(Math.toRadians(180), 100, 100));

    Path2D line4 = new Path2D.Double();
    line4.append(baseLine, true);
    line4.transform(AffineTransform.getTranslateInstance(0, 100));
    line4.transform(AffineTransform.getRotateInstance(Math.toRadians(270), 0, 100));

    Path2D finalPath = new Path2D.Double();
    finalPath.append(line1, true);
    finalPath.append(line2, true);
    finalPath.append(line3, true);
    finalPath.append(line4, true);

    finalPath.closePath();

    return finalPath;
}
```

[image]

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.geom.AffineTransform;
import java.awt.geom.Path2D;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Main();
    }

    public Main() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        public TestPane() {
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(400, 400);
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
            g2d.setColor(Color.RED);
            Path2D path = worldContext();
            int x = (getWidth() - path.getBounds().width) / 2;
            int y = (getHeight()- path.getBounds().height) / 2;
            g2d.translate(x, y);
            g2d.draw(path);
            g2d.dispose();
        }

        protected Path2D worldContext() {
            // Our "base line" line
            Path2D baseLine = new Path2D.Double();
            baseLine.moveTo(0, 0);
            baseLine.lineTo(100, 0);

            // Top line
            Path2D line1 = new Path2D.Double();
            line1.append(baseLine, true);

            Path2D line2 = new Path2D.Double();
            line2.append(baseLine, true);
            line2.transform(AffineTransform.getTranslateInstance(100, 0));
            line2.transform(AffineTransform.getRotateInstance(Math.toRadians(90), 100, 0));

            Path2D line3 = new Path2D.Double();
            line3.append(baseLine, true);
            line3.transform(AffineTransform.getTranslateInstance(100, 100));
            line3.transform(AffineTransform.getRotateInstance(Math.toRadians(180), 100, 100));

            Path2D line4 = new Path2D.Double();
            line4.append(baseLine, true);
            line4.transform(AffineTransform.getTranslateInstance(0, 100));
            line4.transform(AffineTransform.getRotateInstance(Math.toRadians(270), 0, 100));

            Path2D finalPath = new Path2D.Double();
            finalPath.append(line1, true);
            finalPath.append(line2, true);
            finalPath.append(line3, true);
            finalPath.append(line4, true);

            finalPath.closePath();

            return finalPath;
        }

    }
}
```

## A "possible" local context...

This basically applies a transformation to an existing `Path` on each step.  Because it's applying it to an existing `Path`, you need to keep in mind that you're rotation point is actually the start point of the line, which is something that just messes with my head

```
protected Path2D localContext() {
    // Our "base line" line
    Path2D baseLine = new Path2D.Double();
    baseLine.moveTo(0, 0);
    baseLine.lineTo(100, 0);

    Path2D next = modify(baseLine, 0, 0, 0);

    // Top line
    Path2D path = new Path2D.Double();
    path.append(next, false);

    next = modify(next, 100, 0, 90);
    path.append(next, false);

    next = modify(next, 100, 0, 90);
    path.append(next, false);

    next = modify(next, 100, 0, 90);
    path.append(next, false);

    return path;
}

protected Path2D modify(Path2D path, double x, double y, double angle) {
    AffineTransform at = AffineTransform.getTranslateInstance(x, y);
    at.rotate(Math.toRadians(angle), 0, 0);
    Shape shape = path.createTransformedShape(at);
    Path2D newPath = new Path2D.Double(shape);
    return newPath;
}
```

Comment: All this copying from one shape to another isn’t really necessary. Further, the transformation can be simplified to a rotation around the center of the polygon. So, after creating `baseLine`, you simply do `baseLine .append(baseLine.createTransformedShape(AffineTransform.getQuadrantRotateInstance(1, 50, 50)), true); baseLine.append(baseLine.createTransformedShape(AffineTransform .getQuadrantRotateInstance(2, 50, 50)), true);  baseLine.closePath();`, then it contains the desired shape. The first appending of a rotated line make it a shape of two lines, appending it again to itself makes four.

Comment: @holger My "over all" issue is, why do any of it at all anyway , but I've only got what the OP is telling me.  It's also possible that you don't want the combined shapes append, but are simply taking a "line" and a local rotation ... again, I don't know

Comment: I suppose, if you want to be able to fill a shape or do an interior hit test, you have no choice but to assemble a complete shape object.